Chrome android browser rounding PX values very slightly
I have been working on a website where the header has the logo on the left hand side on a white background and the navigation links are on the right hand side on a blue background.  The white and blue backgrounds have a slanted transition between them.  There is also a small bar above the header with contact details.  This is a basic version of the design - https://unique-baklava-926a7a.netlify.app/


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #3587e4;
}

.spacer {
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
}

.child {
  height: 59px;
}

.child:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #fff;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  background: #1e60aa;
  clip-path: polygon(29px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin-right: -1px;
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #1e60aa;
}
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>



The site has been built and all seemed okay until testing on a Google Pixel 7 Pro using Chrome.  I've noticed you can see a small section of the white background under the slanted transition between white and blue.
This screenshot shows the issue.
This screenshot shows is zoomed in on the issue.  It also shows a much smaller line above the flex-row element where the body colour is coming through.

I've also noticed that despite the height of the child elements being set to 59px, Chrome is rendering them at 58.996px.
I phone has a reduced display size on in the OS settings, reverting this to default does resolve the issue.  However, so does leaving the reduced display size on and removing the spacer element from the DOM.
Any ideas how I can resolve this without removing the spacer element or changing the device display size settings.
Chrome version 131.0.6778.81 Android app.

Instead of drawing the notch using 3 elements in the flex-row , you could draw the same thing using a simple linear-gradient.
Here's a demo with the code from the question:


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #3587e4;
}

.spacer {
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #fff 70px, #1e60aa 71px);
}

.child {
  height: 59px;
}

.child:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>



You can still keep the children elements to position things, but no need to set their backgrounds, do that in the container. This way, you will avoid the half pixels and other issues that can happen with dealing with multiple elements like this.

As a side note, the method you are using is mostly outdated. Unless it is for email, that has limitations on the CSS properties that can be used, I would not recommend having multiple elements to generate shapes and backgrounds.
